# How to manage keyboard backlight on MSI Alpha 15 2021

Tags: keyboard, backlight, msi

I recently dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu. It is msi alpha 15 with ryzen 7 5800h. The backlight just stays on always whenever i use Ubuntu.
It doesn't have steelseries keyboard. It's maybe different.
I tried installing openrgb package but it is net detecting keyboard. Also i used

```
xset -led 3
```

Nothing is working. Any help is appreciated. Sorry i am new here so question is not concise.

Comment: I would start with a BIOS update, if available. Also, do add the outputs of `lsb_release -rd` and `uname -r`.

Comment: You r question is a bit confused I will make a leap and say you have a Steelseries keyboard. If so I do as well there is no Ubuntu support for that keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop, and I run Arch linux. The keyboard RGB can be changed by using the [script](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/uploads/78c4e5c598147d6d8a66c2d59a4b19cd/msi-mystic-1563.py) mentioned in the [OpenRGB issue](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/2289).

You might need to change MYSTIC_VID and MYSTIC_PID varaibles in the script to values in the output of lsusb.